# Python variable scope and UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

I don't understand the error in this example. Shouldn't `print(b)` print `6`, by the Python LEGB rule? When the interpreter scans `f(a)` function in line 2, does it  memorize that `b = 33` and puts in the memory heap or  just remembers the information that `b` is a local variable?

```
b = 6
def f(a):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    b = 33
f(20)
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 3):

When Python scans your functions it sees an assignment to `b`. This assignment creates specific bytecode (`LOAD FAST`) that instructs Python to load the name `b` as a local variable.

You can see this if you disassemble the bytecode (using the `dis` module) created for the function `f`:

```
from dis import dis
dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP

  3           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 POP_TOP
```

the relevant instruction here is:

```
LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
```

which loads the name `b` as a local variable.

When `print(b)` is encountered, it tries to load the name `b` but `b` hasn't been defined yet (the assignment has not been performed): you referenced it (`print(b)`) before an assignment to it has been made.

Comment: The dis module  shows what's going on. Does it  work by reading the whole body of the function, and then after that prints the bytecode on the screen, or does it print after each line scan?

Comment: Everything `dis` needs to create what you see is located in `f.__code__`, it doesn't read anything, it uses what already exists @MarkoSavic